# Postgres function to loop GRANT statements

Tags: postgresql

I have a number of `GRANT`s I need to make in a Postgres databas -- Is it possible to put statements like

`GRANT SELECT ON TABLE tablename_xxx TO xxx_group;`

inside of a Postgres SQL function?

Comment: "in side the postgres function." <-- The what??

Comment: I mean - inside the user defined function

Comment: Yep, you can do that. Don't know why you would want to, but you can.

Comment: Thankyou Chris 
Basically I have a set of Grant commands 
I want to write a loop and pass the table names as parameters so that the function can be very minimal

Answer (score 1):

I believe you *can* do this, but in practice you are probably better off writing an external script to do it instead:  Having a Postgres function (pl/pgsql or similar) hanging around just to do `GRANT`s is overkill, where a simple shell script (or PowerShell if you're on Windows) could do the job.

I consider `GRANT` to be part of the DDL functionality of Postgres, and it's generally a good practice to not write functions that use DDL statements (Just as you would probably not write a function to create tables).

Comment: You are correct, as per the suggestion I wrote the external script and its working great. 
Thanku